# forward vpn traffic from tun1 to tun0

Tags: iptables, routing, openwrt, masquerade

I've been banging my head on this for a while and gave up trying to figure it out. My knowledge about routing and iptables is just too limited to understand this it seems.

I have configured a split routing situation on my openwrt router. one computer in my network is using a vpn service to connect to the internet (192.168.10.160, tun1). from my home network i can access this computer through its normal ip. Whenever I'm on the road I can access my home network through a vpn server (tun0). I can access all computers on my home network except for the one that is configured for split routing. No matter what I try I can not forward the traffic from tun0 to tun1.

Does anyone know how this works?

Split routing up script in openvpn:

```
vpn_route_table=10
vpn_inside_net=192.168.10.160/32

iptables -t nat -A delegate_prerouting -i $dev -j zone_wan_prerouting
iptables -t nat -A delegate_postrouting -o $dev -j zone_wan_postrouting

ip route flush table $vpn_route_table
ip route add default via $ifconfig_remote table $vpn_route_table
ip rule add from $vpn_inside_net table $vpn_route_table
```

Routing table:

```
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
10 vpn
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
```

Iptables rule to forward lan traffic:
cat /etc/firewall.user

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o br-lan -j MASQUERADE
```

ifconfig:

```
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:4A:00:FC:48:E9
          inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd61:6126:284f::1/60 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fefc:48e9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:74320006 errors:0 dropped:34 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97509595 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:32077369688 (29.8 GiB)  TX bytes:116317974636 (108.3 GiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:4A:00:FC:48:E9
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:5

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:4A:00:FC:48:EC
          inet addr:70.36.58.57  Bcast:70.36.58.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fefc:48ec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46202978 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:6 frame:0
          TX packets:38951997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:375520214 (358.1 MiB)  TX bytes:3975201183 (3.7 GiB)
          Interrupt:4

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:29057 (28.3 KiB)  TX bytes:29057 (28.3 KiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:1335093 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:2582247 (2.4 MiB)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.162.1.6  P-t-P:10.162.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4138786 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2441546 errors:0 dropped:89167 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:1241129775 (1.1 GiB)  TX bytes:411691697 (392.6 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:4A:00:FC:48:EA
          inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fefc:48ea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21731405 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27355975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1631361559 (1.5 GiB)  TX bytes:921843710 (879.1 MiB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C0:4A:00:FC:48:EB
          inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fefc:48eb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:57896641 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75812276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:503025926 (479.7 MiB)  TX bytes:666046315 (635.1 MiB)
```